# Cartan decomposition of a unitary group?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

For local fields $F$, we consider two case 
1) $E$=quadratic extension of $F$ , 2) $E = F \times F$.

Let V be a 2-dim hermition space over E.

In 1) case, by Cartan decompostion $U(2)$ can be decomposed as $KMK$. (here, $K$ is a compact subgroup of $U(2)$ and M={$x \in E^\times  | \left\vert x \right\vert
 \le 1 $}

In 2) case, $U(2)=GL_2 (F)$ the cartan decomposition of $U(2)$ is $KMK$ where $K$ is compact subgroup and $M$={ $\begin{pmatrix}
 x & 0 \\\
 0 & y
\end{pmatrix} \in GL_{2}(F)$
 | $|x|\le|y|$ }.

My question arises here.

If we consider $U(1)$, then, how can we think the Cartan decomposition of it in the above two cases? I don't know what the above $M$ should be in these case.

Comment: Dear anonymous, If you have previously posted this question on Math.SE, it is good to post a link to here to that question (and there to this question).  Also, I disagree with Marc Palm that this question is too elementary for this site, but it could be explained more clearly.  (E.g. $K$ should probably be a *maximal* compact subgroup; also, do you really mean to work over a number field, rather than a local field.  E.g. for a local field, $| x| \leq 1$ has a definite meaning; for a number field, it raises the question of which absolute value you intend to use.)  Regards, 

Comment: Dear Emerton. Thank you for your kind reply. I am very sorry for not asking the question clearly. There was a little hasting in posting this. Here, K is maximal compact subgroup as you indicated and I am asking it in local fields case.(especially real and p-adic field)

This is the link that connect to the post in mathstackexchange regarding this.

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243291/cartan-decomposition-of-unitary-group

Best,


Comment: 1. Please edit your question such that it will mansion that $F$ is a local field . 

2. please take care about the (2) subscript in the definition of $M$. Probably you just need to replace (2) by {2}. 

I'll try to answer your question soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me formulate the Cartan decomposition for a reductive group over a local field (for more information see e.g. http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~bernstei/Unpublished_texts/unpublished_texts/Bernstein93new-harv.lect.from-chic.pdf section 2.1):

Let $G$ be a reductive group defined over  over a local field $F$ of characteristic $0$.
Let $A$ be the maximal split torus. That is, the  maximal algebraic subgroup defined over $F$ of $G$ which is isomorphic to $(F^{\times})^k$ for some $k$. Note that it is unique   up to a conjugation. Let $K$ be the maximal compact subgroup of $G$. Note that in the Archemedian case it is an algebraic subgroup and it is unique   up to conjugation. In the non-Archemedian it is not algebraic and often it is not unique   up to a conjugation. If your group is defined over the ring of integers $O$ of $F$, you can take $K=G(O)$.

The week version of Cartan decomposition says: $$G=KAK.$$

For the stronger version, let $\Lambda=Mor(F^\times, A)$ be the group of co-characters of $A$. Let $\Lambda^{++}$ be the Wile chamber of $\Lambda$. ruffly spicing it is the fundamental domain for $W:=N_G(A)/Z_G(A)$. We have an obvious map $\Lambda \times F^\times \to A$. Let $A^+$  be:\
1. In the Archemedian case the image of $\Lambda^{++} \times \mathbb{R}_{>0}$.
2. In the non-Archemedian  case the image of $\Lambda^{++} \times \pi$, where $\pi$ is the uniformizer of $F$.

Than $$G=KA^+K.$$ Moreover, any $K\times K$ double co-set have a unique  element from $A^+$.

The case of $U(1)$, this is not that interesting. First of all the group is commutative, so we do not need to  write $K$ twice. In the non-split case, the group is compact, then $A$ is trivial and the Cartan decomposition says $G=K$. In the split case, $A$ is one dimensional and $A^+$ is either $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ or $\pi^\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment:   Dear Rami, I have no word to thank you enough. It helped me very much. Though I am not so sure that how your answer is in well-harmony in the above U(2) case, but I think that this comes from my ignorances. I will study the material you recommended and then I will meditate it again. Best regards, 
 